# После обновления плагина kotlin проект не запускается

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

При запуске проекта возникает ошибка:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;
```

> build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> build.gradle(Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "avirtel.az.dominospizza"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    //  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    compileOnly "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Как с этим быть?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44202463/5698593

Comment: Уже вышел 1.1.61, обновитесь еще раз, вдруг? :)

Comment: Была подобная проблема. После обновления Kotlin плагина до `v1.2.0-release-Studio3.0-1` не воспроизводится.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать очистку проекта (Build - Clean Project) а потом синхронизацию gradle.

Мне помогало.